# How to verify authenticated user for each valid page request

Tags: php, http, authentication, web

I want only logged-in users to be able to access ANY content on an experimental PHP web app I'm developing, but I'd like to avoid calling an authentication script on all pages that I create (no specific reason for that).

I was thinking along the lines of redirecting all valid requests which result in HTTP response code 200 to a PHP script which checks for an authenticated user and on success, redirects them to the requested page using the $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] value.

I'd like to know if this is possible? If yes, Are there pitfalls in this method?

Comment: You should have a security method/page which checks for existing and valid session, which is autoloaded(autoincluded) on each page

Comment: If you use MVC architecture, try to use **filters** and **routers**

Comment: @Royal Bg Sounds interesting, what would be an efficient way to auto-include my auth script?

Comment: an autoload method - http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you're working on an OOP Website you could just include/call your script on your template page, like this you can call your authentication script on all pages at the same time

Comment: Thanks, any good resources you can point me to in this regard? Specifically, building OOP based PHP templates.

Comment: You're welcome. You can read a lot about OOP on php.net

[here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php)

or you might want to watch a few videos from phpacademy on youtube